# What is the fastest way of selecting 2 columns from the same (random) record in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want I retrieve a pair of columns from the same record, in a random basis. I've heard that Rand is very inefficient, however, so I'd like to use a different way. (Lots of articles claims so, including http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/).

So yeah, my title pretty much says it all.
Example:
Records:
12, James, Clarinet, Chicken
16, Billy, Drums, Bacon
15, Shane, Guitar, Pizza

The system would randomly pick a record. It'll then
echo 'A boy named $firstname likes $favoritefood'.

Something like that. Help?

Comment: Are you trying to randomly find a row or randomly find a column(s) in a given row (or both)? The only way to "randomly find a column" would be in the middle-tier. The SQL language is not designed for dynamic column generation.

Comment: Hmm, if so, what would be the best way to do what I'm asking?

Comment: Just so you know, the solution you marked as the answer is just finding a random row. That's obviously different than pulling a random column from a random row.

Comment: @Thomas That's what the user is asking for. He wants to select 2 columns (represented by $firstname and $favoritefood) from a random record (or row).

Comment: @dragonmantank - Agreed. I now noticed the edits. The original version hinted to the idea of wanting a random column but that appears not to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard disclaimer about SQL injection. This should work, but I didn't try it:

```
// Get the number of rows in the table
$count = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `count` FROM `table`'));
// Use those to generate a random number
$rand = rand(1,$count['count']);
// Select the two columns we need, and use limit to set the boundaries
$query = 'SELECT `firstName`, `favoriteFood` FROM `table` LIMIT '.$rand.',1';
// Run the query
if(($result = mysql_query($query)) !== FALSE) {
    // Dump the result into two variables
    list($firstname, $favoritefood) = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // Echo out the result
    echo 'A boy named '.$firstname.' likes '.$favoritefood;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I fell asleep. I'm going to try this out soon though. It looks very nice! But can you tell me more of how I can prevent an attack?

Comment: Generally you would use mysql_real_escape_string on any variables you would be using to create a query. Finding the count is pretty safe, since that result is always a numeric value, but it never hurts to be safe. You can also use PDO and prepared statements to be even safer.

Answer (score 0):

what about this ?

```
select ... from tableT limit $i,1
```

$i should be random number between 0 and number of rows in tableT

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really following how I can get specific column pairs with this.