# What is the fastest way of selecting 2 columns from the same (random) record in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the fastest way of selecting 2 columns from the same (random) record in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521037/what-is-the-fastest-way-of-selecting-2-columns-from-the-same-random-record-in-m)

I want I retrieve a pair of columns from the same record, in a random basis. I've heard that Rand is very inefficient, however, so I'd like to use a different way. (Lots of articles claims so, including http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/).

So yeah, my title pretty much says it all. Example: Records:

```
12, James, Clarinet, Chicken
16, Billy, Drums, Bacon
15, Shane, Guitar, Pizza
```

The system would randomly pick a record. It'll then echo 'A boy named $firstname likes $favoritefood'.

Something like that. Help?

Comment: from the article **you** linked to: "get the minimum and maximum id values in the entire table" and then select a random number within that range.

Comment: Nah, it's just midnight, tired, and I'm eager for an answer before I sleep, since I think my other thread has already been overshadowed. You canc lose this if its against the rules or something

Comment: Are those ID, Name, Instrument, Food ? the 4 columns depicted ? Out of which you only need Name and Food ?

Comment: yes, it's purely for example though (if you think I'm creating a project necessitating that hah)

Answer (score 1):

Well :-? Here's some code:

```
<?php
$total=mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`;');
$total=mysql_fetch_array($total);
$total=$total[0];

$row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT '.mt_rand(0,$total-1).', 1;'));
?>
```

What this does, is find the current row count then use LIMIT to specifically target a random row, it works in a similar manner to rownum in oracle... similar.

Comment: Am I missing something? I echoed row, and just got the word 'array'.

Comment: try print_r($row) or var_dump($row)... as the name implies, mysql_fetch_array() returns an array with all the fields you selected.

Comment: Just tried it and um... that's not really what I wanted hah. This is what I really want: <a href="/' . $link["link"] . '.php">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imagetitle/' . $pic["pic"] . '" 
                   alt="' . $alt["alt"] . '" 
              /> //in this, I want to display a random record containing the same $image, $link, and $alt.

Comment: nice enough for upvote; @user657847: Next time put your wishes in original question.